# Run echo example from Jshell

Tags: java, jshell

I read such a command line arguments example:

```java
public class Echo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

It runs properly from command line, how could I run it from Jshell?

```
jshell> Echo.main testing
|  created variable testing, however, it cannot be referenced until class main is declared
```

It report error that failed to be referenced.

Comment: Just use a normal `System.out.println`?

Comment: Are you running that class definition in jshell?
After that you can simply run Echo.main(new String[] {"arg1", "arg2"})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoke it as any other static method:

```
Echo.main(new String[] { "hello", "world" });
```

Full session:

```
$ jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.8
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> public class Echo {
   ...>     public static void main (String[] args) {
   ...>         for (String s: args) {
   ...>             System.out.println(s);
   ...>         }
   ...>     }
   ...> }
|  created class Echo

jshell> Echo.main(new String[] { "hello", "world" });
hello
world
```

Note that you can declare your `main` method as follows:

```
public static void main(String... args) { ... }
```

This is binary compatible with `String[] args` syntax, but would allow you to invoke it as follows:

```
Echo.main("hello", "world");
```